# Is it possible to restrict operations on Amazon S3 objects based on their Last-Modified date?

Tags: amazon-s3

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I want to create an IAM policy for S3 which doesn't allow the user to delete in general, but allows them to rename objects and give them the prefix `trash/`. I then want to allow them to delete objects with the `trash/` prefix, but only if the Last-Modified date is sufficiently far in the past.

The idea is to limit the damage that could be done if the key is compromised, while still allowing deletes.

From my reading of the documentation, I don't think this is possible but I thought I'd check the wisdom of teh Internets first.

**Update:**

It should now possible to achieve something very close to my original aim using Amazon's new Object Expiration Policies:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't look like its possible to restrict actions by `Last-Modified date` although I don't know for sure. But why don't you try this.

1. Prevent your users from deleting objects via an `IAM policy`
2. Implement whatever psuedo delete you like. eg rename files, move to another bucket etc. (possibly preventing your users from seeing these files)
3. Have an automated/scheduled task (eg once a day) that actually deletes these files if the `Last-Modified` condition is met.

Comment: Thanks Geoff. That was my original plan but, for security reasons, it's going to involve having a separate machine to run the scheduled job from and I wondered if it was possible to get away with a simpler setup.